# JQuery Datatables not searching by hidden value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable that contains inputs of type hidden that is in the first td element.

The problem when I type the value in the search bar it doesn't pick it up. It works fine on my local computer, but on the live version it doesn't work.

I checked several times and all the code is exactly the same. All the other functions of the datatable works perfectly. It searches fine on the visible values.

Here is an example. If i search for the hidden value '12345' it wont work on live:

```
<table id="merchant-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Surname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>John</td>
               <td>Doe <input type='hidden' value='12345'/></td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the hidden value in a new column and use DataTables to change it's visibility.

http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible

[http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().visible()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns%28%29.visible%28%29)

http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns